# Is it possible to use CSS Counters to set/override the `seed` attribute of an SVG Filter's <feTurbulence> element?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG `<filter>` defined in the HTML document body, which I use to apply a texture to other elements via their respective CSS `filter:` rules. Everything works correctly. ✨

- Is there any way to set the `<feTurbulence>` element's `seed` attribute via the CSS *at the point the filter is applied*, so that I could provide a CSS counter as the value?
- I know how to do this via JavaScript; I'm wondering whether it's possible via HTML/CSS/SVG alone.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That would help answering the question.

Comment: A counter value is replaced content of a CSS pseudo-element, `seed` is an XML attribute, how would you get one to the other? There is the CSS `attr()` to transfer attribute data to CSS properties, but the other way round, XML/HTML does not read CSS, period.

Comment: @ccprog are counters really only usable in pseudo content? I know it's been ages since I used them, but I could have sworn they were usable in `calc()` statements as well. Anyway, I have a good understanding of the relationship between CSS and HTML, but I also know that some aspects of SVG's can be overridden via CSS *(e.g. `fill`)*, so that's the area I was seeking more info. Good to know I was missing something else though, thank you. I suppose I can mark this as answered.